# How to execute ffmpeg via php on Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, php, cmd.exe

This is my script:

```
echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n<br>";
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:01:30.35 -vframes 1 img.png"; 
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

When I run it from CMD it works just fine but nothing happens when I run it from php. I have tried both `exec` and `shell_exec`.
I have heard I should run ffmpeg as a background process. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
system($cmd);
```

You won't need `echo`. This should work.